# Reference table value in text

Tags: tables, hyperref, cross-referencing, pgfplotstable

I want to be able to reference a table value in my text (this is because I often update my tables, and then list the specific values in the text).  Here is an example table I would use:

```
% Example Table
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{filecontents*}{scientists.csv}
name,surname,age
Albert,Einstein,133
Marie,Curie,145
Thomas,Edison,165
\end{filecontents*}

% Read in Table


  \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep=comma,
    string type,
    columns/name/.style={column name=Name, column type={|l}},
    columns/surname/.style={column name=Surname, column type={|l}},
    columns/age/.style={column name=Age, column type={|c|}},
    every head row/.style={before row=\hline,after row=\hline},
    every last row/.style={after row=\hline},
    ]{scientists.csv}
\end{document}
```

I may want to be able to reference a given scientists age in the text by a reference of his/her name (ie,:)

```
Albert Einstein is \ref{albert} years old.
```

Ideally, this would still be using pgfplotstable because it is how I currently read in many tables.  Thanks,

Comment: `\firstname` is not defined. Do you intend it to be `\surename`?

Comment: Thanks -- had copied in wrong example from here:http://texblog.org/tag/pgfplotstable/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another alternative without modifying the data is via `\pgfplotstablegetelem`...`\pgfplotsretval` pair. Note that the row index starts from 0 instead of 1.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{filecontents*}{scientists.csv}
name,surname,age
Albert,Einstein,133
Marie,Curie,145
Thomas,Edison,165
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{scientists.csv}\mytable
\def\getcell#1#2#3{
\pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{#2}\of{#3}\pgfplotsretval%
}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    string type,
    columns/name/.style={column name=Name, column type={|l}},
    columns/surname/.style={column name=Surname, column type={|l}},
    columns/age/.style={column name=Age, column type={|c|}},
    every head row/.style={before row=\hline,after row=\hline},
    every last row/.style={after row=\hline},
    ]\mytable

\bigskip

\getcell{0}{name}{\mytable} \getcell{0}{surname}{\mytable} is \getcell{0}{age}{\mytable} 
years old. \getcell{1}{name}{\mytable} \getcell{1}{surname}{\mytable} is 
\getcell{1}{age}{\mytable} years old. But \getcell{2}{name}{\mytable} 
\getcell{2}{surname}{\mytable} is still older, he is \getcell{2}{age}{\mytable} years old.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is awesome, but the new functions returns an extra space -- any way to get rid of that?

Comment: @mike Yes sorry I'm missing a percent sign in the definition of `getcell`, replace that line with `\def\getcell#1#2#3{%`

Comment: Perfect -- really appreciate the response @percusse

Comment: @mike My pleaseure :)

Answer (score 3):

If it is an option to have your csv files suitably prepared, try this (here I bundled the filecontents thing and the table in one latex source)

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\printandsetlabel#1#2#3{#2\setcounter{#1}{#2}%
 \protected@edef\@currentlabel
 {\csname p@#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname}%
 \label{#3}}
\makeatother

\newcounter{age}
\newcommand*{\age}[2]{\printandsetlabel{age}{#1}{#2}}

\begin{filecontents*}{scientists.csv}
name,surname,age
Albert,Einstein,\age{133}{albert}
Marie,Curie,\age{145}{marie}
Thomas,Edison,\age{165}{thomas}
\end{filecontents*}

% Read in Table

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}\hsize8cm
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep=comma,
    string type,
    columns/name/.style={column name=Name, column type={|l}},
    columns/surname/.style={column name=Surname, column type={|l}},
    columns/age/.style={column name=Age, column type={|c|}},
    every head row/.style={before row=\hline,after row=\hline},
    every last row/.style={after row=\hline},
    ]{scientists.csv}

\bigskip
Albert Einstein is \ref{albert} years old and Marie Curie is \ref{marie} years
old. But Thomas Edison is still older, he is \ref{thomas} years old.
\end{document}
```

[image: outcome of the code]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, but I am not actually making the table in Tex, so the answer below is preferred.

Comment: @mike: thanks for looking at my proposal. Preparing the table (I think you mean the `.csv` file) does not need TeX, but of course if you need to use the same table with some other software, then you will not want to have the added `\age` things...